# What caused this unhelpful Powershell ISE error message?

Tags: powershell-ise

I'm trying to use Powershell ISE as a console app with little success. Comskip is a command line tool and I'm having a AHK script executing the Comskip commercial stipping normally through `cmd.exe`. Works fine, but lately I started using Unicode characters (star-rating) in the filenames and as you all know these won't display especially good in the console.

Investigation led me to Powershell ISE which is supposed to support Unicode. Running Comskip from ISE proved to be quite challenging. It works fine if typing in everything manually, but the problem starts when calling it from an another script.

Now the problematic part is if using the code calling the ordinary Powershell console it all went fine. But the same code calling the ISE fails and I can't see why. Can any of you? The error message I get doesn't give any explicit clues on what went wrong. The error message only says:

> *Usage: `powershell_ise.exe` or `powershell_ise.exe fileName.ps1`*

The AHK line calling the ISE looks like this:

```
latest_file := "C:\Program\Comskip\q.ts"
Run, PowerShell_ISE.exe "C:\Program\Comskip\comskip.exe" -t --videoredo "%latest_file%"
```

Now if using the Powershell console the same code executes alright:

```
latest_file := "C:\Program\Comskip\q.ts"
Run, PowerShell.exe "C:\Program\Comskip\comskip.exe" -t --videoredo "%latest_file%"
```

How come I get these anomalies?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell ISE does not have ability to run commands like powershell.exe has. Reason for that is simple: ISE was designed as an interactive environment where powershell.exe had been thought out as something both for interactive and "batch" operations, like the one you tried to complete.

The error you get is IMO descriptive enough: you can only run PowerShell_ISE (no paramters) or specify .ps1 file that ISE will open once it started. In v3 there are 2 new added ( -NoProfile and -MTA) but still - nobody designed it as batch processing tool.. sorry.